# Urban Airship sending notifications after Logout

Tags: android

I'm working in an application which integrates UA. Right now the app is able to receive notifications without any problems. However there's a problem I'm facing.

When the user logs out of the application. I'm setting an empty alias by calling `PushManager.shared().setAlias("");` however, the device is still able to receive notifications from the previous user.

Another problem related. User A logs into the app, logs out, then user B logs into the app. After doing this, the device is still receiving notifications for user A.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server needs to keep track of which user is associated with which DEVICE ID. That means when a user signs in, associate that DEVICE ID to him. If a user signs out dissociate that DEVICE ID with him

That way if multiple users sign in and out on the same device, you'll know what information to send the device (depending on who the DEVICE ID is associated with at that moment)

I keep a "USERS" table that has a columns for DEVICE ID and USER ID

**Also if a user logs out, then there wouldn't be a DEVICE ID associated to him. So you just wouldn't send any notification in that scenario

Comment: Thanks! that's what I thought the process should be, just needed confirmation.